# TTS engine : speak failed: TTS engine connection not fully set up

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I'm trying to use android google tts . And it worked really fine when it was first page to start but when I changed it to second page. The tts is not working and I don't know how
I've already done

```
<queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TTS_SERVICE" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

adding this in the manifest and all the other permission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

This is my OnInitListener

```
    private TextToSpeech.OnInitListener ttsInitListener = new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() //시작할떄 사용되는 listnenr
    {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status)
        {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                _tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(completedListener);
            }
            else{
                return;
            }


        }
    };
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code!!! TT

++ add)
Is it because of the AsyncTask?
I change MainActivity to other activity
That's why tts is not bound?

Answer (score 0):

I think tts.speak() act faster than tts.onInitListener
So I add handler.postDelay. Now It's working !!